# Java.security.Access.ControlException: access denied("java.io.FilePermission" "[object file]" "read")

Tags: java, applet, access-denied, getparameter

I have the following problem:

I have a Java program that receives via Applet a binary file.

I received that file with `getParameter(file)` and read that file with `java.io.FileInputStream(file)`.

I put this file on web server and call the java program via javascript

First, when I was running the program, was occuring the message error:

```
Java.security.Access.ControlException: access denied("java.io.FilePermission" "[object file]" "read")
```

I created a key via `keytool` and signed the jar file with `jarsigner`.

But, even executing the command `jarsigner`, when I run the Java program again, the error message continues occuring:

```
Java.security.Access.ControlException: access denied("java.io.FilePermission" "[object file]" "read").
```

Therefore, the error persists even after signing.

I really do not know what to do.

Can anyone help me?

Below the java code:

```
public class InJava extends Applet{
    String parametro;    
    public void sayHello() {

        parametro = getParameter("parametro");

        java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;

        try  {
            fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(parametro);
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            String retorno_exc = e.toString();
            return ;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in [AccessController.doPrivileged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html), like:

```
public class InJava extends Applet{

  public void sayHello() {

    final String parametro = getParameter("parametro");

    FileInputStream fis =  AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<FileInputStream>() {
      public FileInputStream run() {
        try  {
          retrun new FileInputStream(parametro);
        } catch (IOException e)  {
          // handle exception
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Make sure that your applet jar(s) are signed, and that you understand [all](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) [other](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml) [consequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/secman.html) of [running](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/manifest.html) an [applet](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/signed_code.xml).